# Different size, different product SQL

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to create a database that, every product with the same name but different size will have different attributes: price, images, videos but has all the other attributes stay the same: description, ingredients, details. How could I make something like that (just like this: [example](http://www.sephora.com/bi-facil-double-action-eye-makeup-remover-P54477?skuId=534628&icid2=products%20grid:p54477))? Thank you.

Comment: This is basically asking "How do I do data modeling" - perhaps search that for some tutorials?  I do not see how any answer would assist in teaching you that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `product` table with the general caracteritics

```
product_id, name, description, details
```

and then an `sku`  table with a fk to `product`

```
sku_id, product_id (fk), price, images, video
```